# Carrying over static variable

Tags: java

I am trying to setup a Minesweeper game however I am having problems carrying over the new 'v' int into the board file. Below is a list of things I have done.I hope what I have said below makes sense, the original minesweeeper base game code can be found at the bottom of this.

- Made an Easy.java file that contains:

  ```
  import java.util.Scanner;

  public class Easy{
      public static int b;

      public static void setVariable(int s)
      {
          b = s;
      }

      public static int getVariable()
      {
          return b;
      }  
  }
  ```
- Added a public static int to the top of Mines.java (under `private final int FRAME_HEIGHT = 290;`)
- Added to the main method withing the public void run of the Mines.java file:

  ```
  System.out.println("Please enter number for difficulty");
  System.out.println("1: Easy 2: Medium 3: Hard");
  Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
  int difficulty = kb.nextInt();
  System.out.println("Difficulty set to: " + difficulty);                
  if(difficulty==1){
      Easy.setVariable(40);
      v = Easy.getVariable();
      System.out.println(v);
      System.out.println("Easy mode chosen");
  }
  ```
- I am just unsure on how to link the Board.java file to take the value of 'v' I have tried

  ```
  int N_MINES = Mines.v;
  ```

However it doesn't see any value I set in the above piece of code however if I set v to equal a number it see's this. In the previous code where I do "System.out.println(v);" it prints out the correct variable however the Board.java does not see this number. How am I supposed to go about this?

Board.java:

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

import java.util.Random;
import java.util.*;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Board extends JPanel {

    private final int NUM_IMAGES = 13;
    private final int CELL_SIZE = 15;

    private final int COVER_FOR_CELL = 10;
    private final int MARK_FOR_CELL = 10;
    private final int EMPTY_CELL = 0;
    private final int MINE_CELL = 9;
    private final int COVERED_MINE_CELL = MINE_CELL + COVER_FOR_CELL;
    private final int MARKED_MINE_CELL = COVERED_MINE_CELL + MARK_FOR_CELL;

    private final int DRAW_MINE = 9;
    private final int DRAW_COVER = 10;
    private final int DRAW_MARK = 11;
    private final int DRAW_WRONG_MARK = 12;

    int N_MINES = Mines.v;

    private int N_ROWS = 16;
    private int N_COLS = 16;

    private int[] field;
    private boolean inGame;
    private int mines_left;
    private Image[] img;

    private int all_cells;
    private JLabel statusbar;


    public Board(JLabel statusbar) {

        this.statusbar = statusbar;

        img = new Image[NUM_IMAGES];

        for (int i = 0; i < NUM_IMAGES; i++) {
            img[i] = (new ImageIcon(i + ".png")).getImage();
        }

        setDoubleBuffered(true);

        addMouseListener(new MinesAdapter());
        newGame();
    }

    private void newGame() {

        Random random;
        int current_col;

        int i = 0;
        int position = 0;
        int cell = 0;
        /*
        System.out.println("Please enter number for difficulty");
        System.out.println("1: Easy 2: Medium 3: Hard");
        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
        int difficulty = kb.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Difficulty set to: " + difficulty);                

        if(difficulty==1){
           N_MINES=N_MINES*1;
           System.out.println("Easy mode chosen");
        }

        if(difficulty==2){
           N_MINES=N_MINES*2;
           System.out.println("Medium mode chosen");
        }

        if(difficulty==3){
           N_MINES=N_MINES*3;
           System.out.println("Hard mode chosen");
        }        
        */
        random = new Random();
        inGame = true;
        mines_left = N_MINES;

        all_cells = N_ROWS * N_COLS;
        field = new int[all_cells];

        for (i = 0; i < all_cells; i++)
            field[i] = COVER_FOR_CELL;

        statusbar.setText(Integer.toString(mines_left));

        i = 0;
        while (i < N_MINES) {
            position = (int) (all_cells * random.nextDouble());

            if ((position < all_cells) &&
                (field[position] != COVERED_MINE_CELL)) {


                current_col = position % N_COLS;
                field[position] = COVERED_MINE_CELL;
                i++;

                if (current_col > 0) { 
                    cell = position - 1 - N_COLS;
                    if (cell >= 0)
                        if (field[cell] != COVERED_MINE_CELL)
                            field[cell] += 1;
                    cell = position - 1;
                    if (cell >= 0)
                        if (field[cell] != COVERED_MINE_CELL)
                            field[cell] += 1;

                    cell = position + N_COLS - 1;
                    if (cell < all_cells)
                        if (field[cell] != COVERED_MINE_CELL)
                            field[cell] += 1;
                }

                cell = position - N_COLS;
                if (cell >= 0)
                    if (field[cell] != COVERED_MINE_CELL)
                        field[cell] += 1;
                cell = position + N_COLS;
                if (cell < all_cells)
                    if (field[cell] != COVERED_MINE_CELL)
                        field[cell] += 1;

                if (current_col < (N_COLS - 1)) {
                    cell = position - N_COLS + 1;
                    if (cell >= 0)
                        if (field[cell] != COVERED_MINE_CELL)
                            field[cell] += 1;
                    cell = position + N_COLS + 1;
                    if (cell < all_cells)
                        if (field[cell] != COVERED_MINE_CELL)
                            field[cell] += 1;
                    cell = position + 1;
                    if (cell < all_cells)
                        if (field[cell] != COVERED_MINE_CELL)
                            field[cell] += 1;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void find_empty_cells(int j) {

        int current_col = j % N_COLS;
        int cell;

        if (current_col > 0) { 
            cell = j - N_COLS - 1;
            if (cell >= 0)
                if (field[cell] > MINE_CELL) {
                    field[cell] -= COVER_FOR_CELL;
                    if (field[cell] == EMPTY_CELL)
                        find_empty_cells(cell);
                }

            cell = j - 1;
            if (cell >= 0)
                if (field[cell] > MINE_CELL) {
                    field[cell] -= COVER_FOR_CELL;
                    if (field[cell] == EMPTY_CELL)
                        find_empty_cells(cell);
                }

            cell = j + N_COLS - 1;
            if (cell < all_cells)
                if (field[cell] > MINE_CELL) {
                    field[cell] -= COVER_FOR_CELL;
                    if (field[cell] == EMPTY_CELL)
                        find_empty_cells(cell);
                }
        }

        cell = j - N_COLS;
        if (cell >= 0)
            if (field[cell] > MINE_CELL) {
                field[cell] -= COVER_FOR_CELL;
                if (field[cell] == EMPTY_CELL)
                    find_empty_cells(cell);
            }

        cell = j + N_COLS;
        if (cell < all_cells)
            if (field[cell] > MINE_CELL) {
                field[cell] -= COVER_FOR_CELL;
                if (field[cell] == EMPTY_CELL)
                    find_empty_cells(cell);
            }

        if (current_col < (N_COLS - 1)) {
            cell = j - N_COLS + 1;
            if (cell >= 0)
                if (field[cell] > MINE_CELL) {
                    field[cell] -= COVER_FOR_CELL;
                    if (field[cell] == EMPTY_CELL)
                        find_empty_cells(cell);
                }

            cell = j + N_COLS + 1;
            if (cell < all_cells)
                if (field[cell] > MINE_CELL) {
                    field[cell] -= COVER_FOR_CELL;
                    if (field[cell] == EMPTY_CELL)
                        find_empty_cells(cell);
                }

            cell = j + 1;
            if (cell < all_cells)
                if (field[cell] > MINE_CELL) {
                    field[cell] -= COVER_FOR_CELL;
                    if (field[cell] == EMPTY_CELL)
                        find_empty_cells(cell);
                }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

        int cell = 0;
        int uncover = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < N_ROWS; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < N_COLS; j++) {

                cell = field[(i * N_COLS) + j];

                if (inGame && cell == MINE_CELL)
                    inGame = false;

                if (!inGame) {
                    if (cell == COVERED_MINE_CELL) {
                        cell = DRAW_MINE;
                    } else if (cell == MARKED_MINE_CELL) {
                        cell = DRAW_MARK;
                    } else if (cell > COVERED_MINE_CELL) {
                        cell = DRAW_WRONG_MARK;
                    } else if (cell > MINE_CELL) {
                        cell = DRAW_COVER;
                    }


                } else {
                    if (cell > COVERED_MINE_CELL)
                        cell = DRAW_MARK;
                    else if (cell > MINE_CELL) {
                        cell = DRAW_COVER;
                        uncover++;
                    }
                }

                g.drawImage(img[cell], (j * CELL_SIZE),
                    (i * CELL_SIZE), this);
            }
        }

        if (uncover == 0 && inGame) {
            inGame = false;
            statusbar.setText("Game won");
        } else if (!inGame)
            statusbar.setText("Game lost");
    }

    class MinesAdapter extends MouseAdapter {

        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {

            int x = e.getX();
            int y = e.getY();

            int cCol = x / CELL_SIZE;
            int cRow = y / CELL_SIZE;

            boolean rep = false;


            if (!inGame) {
                newGame();
                repaint();
            }


            if ((x < N_COLS * CELL_SIZE) && (y < N_ROWS * CELL_SIZE)) {

                if (e.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON3) {

                    if (field[(cRow * N_COLS) + cCol] > MINE_CELL) {
                        rep = true;

                        if (field[(cRow * N_COLS) + cCol] <= COVERED_MINE_CELL) {
                            if (mines_left > 0) {
                                field[(cRow * N_COLS) + cCol] += MARK_FOR_CELL;
                                mines_left--;
                                statusbar.setText(Integer.toString(mines_left));
                            } else
                                statusbar.setText("No marks left");
                        } else {

                            field[(cRow * N_COLS) + cCol] -= MARK_FOR_CELL;
                            mines_left++;
                            statusbar.setText(Integer.toString(mines_left));
                        }
                    }

                } else {

                    if (field[(cRow * N_COLS) + cCol] > COVERED_MINE_CELL) {
                        return;
                    }

                    if ((field[(cRow * N_COLS) + cCol] > MINE_CELL) &&
                        (field[(cRow * N_COLS) + cCol] < MARKED_MINE_CELL)) {

                        field[(cRow * N_COLS) + cCol] -= COVER_FOR_CELL;
                        rep = true;

                        if (field[(cRow * N_COLS) + cCol] == MINE_CELL)
                            inGame = false;
                        if (field[(cRow * N_COLS) + cCol] == EMPTY_CELL)
                            find_empty_cells((cRow * N_COLS) + cCol);
                    }
                }

                if (rep)
                    repaint();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Mines.java:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import java.util.*;

public class Mines extends JFrame {

    private final int FRAME_WIDTH = 250;
    private final int FRAME_HEIGHT = 290;
    public static int v;

    private final JLabel statusbar;

    public Mines() {

        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(FRAME_WIDTH, FRAME_HEIGHT);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setTitle("Minesweeper");

        statusbar = new JLabel("");
        add(statusbar, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        add(new Board(statusbar));

        setResizable(false);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {                
                JFrame ex = new Mines();
                ex.setVisible(true);

                System.out.println("Please enter number for difficulty");
                System.out.println("1: Easy 2: Medium 3: Hard");
                Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
                int difficulty = kb.nextInt();
                System.out.println("Difficulty set to: " + difficulty);                

                if(difficulty==1){
                  Easy.setVariable(40);
                  v = Easy.getVariable();
                  System.out.println(v);
                  System.out.println("Easy mode chosen");
                }
                if(difficulty==2){
                  //Medium.setVariable(80);
                  //v = Medium.getVariable();
                  //System.out.println(v);
                  System.out.println("Medium mode chosen");                  
                  //Medium.main(args);
                }     
                if(difficulty==3){
                  Hard.main(args);
                } 
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Your static variable is public, therefore doesn't need a setter or a getter method

Comment: Matter of fact, I don't see the purpose of that Easy class... Please show the board class.

Comment: @cricket_007 the board class is too big to paste. If you click the link the first block of java code is the board class

Comment: I've seen much longer code in questions. I think it'd fit. At least a [mcve]

Comment: @cricket_007 I am a bit confused on how I would go about it if I removed the setter and getter method's. would I just leave it as " public static int b;
"

Comment: @cricket_007 I have added it to the question

Comment: `Easy.b` can be gotten and set at any point from any class. That's how public static variables are used (and why they are bad)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit the constructor of the Board class to accept the number of mines.

```
private int n_mines = 40; // default 

public Board(int mines, JLabel statusbar) {
    this.n_mines = mines;
    this.statusbar = statusbar;
```

Make a `new Board(20, new JLabel());` for an easier game

Comment: Doing this works however my dilemma was with changing the 20 in this case to a different value based on what the user chooses (as seen in the Mines.java) code block

Comment: After moving around some code I have made it work to how I need it to work. Thank you!

Comment: You should be picking a different difficulties, then make a new Board object with different number of mines